# Pivot array of structs into columns using pyspark - not explode the array

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I currently have a dataframe with an id and a column which is **an array of structs**:

```
 root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- lists: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- _1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _2: string (nullable = true)
```

Here is an example table with data:

```
 id | list1             | list2
 ------------------------------------------
 1  | [[a, av], [b, bv]]| [[e, ev], [f,fv]]
 2  | [[c, cv]]         | [[g,gv]]
```

How do I transform the above dataframe to the one below? I need to "explode" the array and add columns based on first value in the struct.

```
 id | a   | b   | c   | d   | e  | f  | g  
 ----------------------------------------
 1  | av  | bv  | null| null| ev | fv | null
 2  | null| null| cv  | null|null|null|gv
```

---

A pyspark code to create the dataframe is as below:

```
d1 = spark.createDataFrame([("1", [("a","av"),("b","bv")], [("e", "ev"), ("f", "fv")]), \
                                    ("2", [("c", "cv")],  [("g", "gv")])], ["id","list1","list2"])
```

**Note:** I have a spark version of 2.2.0 so some sql functions don't work such as concat_map, etc.

Comment: can you send the array ?

Comment: @SachinthaNayanajith I added pyspark code

Comment: Use inline or inline_outer to explode array of structs

Comment: @murtihash hey can you provide example using inline/inline_outer can't figure it out..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPD** - For Spark 2.2.0

You can define similar functions in 2.2.0 using udfs. They will be much less efficient in terms of performance and you'll need a special function for each output value type (i.e. you won't be able to have one `element_at` function which could output value of any type from any map type), but they will work. The code below works for Spark 2.2.0:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import MapType, ArrayType, StringType

@udf(MapType(StringType(), StringType()))
def map_from_entries(l):
    return {x:y for x,y in l}

@udf(MapType(StringType(), StringType()))
def map_concat(m1, m2):
    m1.update(m2)
    return m1

@udf(ArrayType(StringType()))
def map_keys(m):
    return list(m.keys())

def element_getter(k):
    @udf(StringType())
    def element_at(m):
        return m.get(k)
    return element_at

d2 = d1.select('id',
               map_concat(map_from_entries('list1'),
                          map_from_entries('list2')).alias('merged_map'))
map_keys = d2.select(f.explode(map_keys('merged_map')).alias('mk')) \
             .agg(f.collect_set('mk').alias('keys')) \
             .collect()[0].keys
map_keys = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
selects = [element_getter(k)('merged_map').alias(k) for k in sorted(map_keys)]
d = d2.select('id', *selects)
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER** (working for Spark 2.4.0+)

Not clear where `d` column came from in your example (`d` never appeared in the initial dataframe). If columns should be created based on the first elements in the array, then this should work (assuming total number of unique first values in the lists is small enough):

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
d2 = d1.select('id',
               f.map_concat(f.map_from_entries('list1'),
                            f.map_from_entries('list2')).alias('merged_map'))
map_keys = d2.select(f.explode(f.map_keys('merged_map')).alias('mk')) \
             .agg(f.collect_set('mk').alias('keys')) \
             .collect()[0].keys
selects = [f.element_at('merged_map', k).alias(k) for k in sorted(map_keys)]
d = d2.select('id', *selects)
```

Output (no column for `d` because it never mentioned in the initial DataFrame):

```
+---+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| id|   a|   b|   c|   e|   f|   g|
+---+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|  1|  av|  bv|null|  ev|  fv|null|
|  2|null|null|  cv|null|null|  gv|
+---+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

If you actually had in mind that list of the columns is fixed from the beginning (and they are not taken from the array), then you can just replace the definition of varaible `map_keys` with the fixed list of columns, e.g. `map_keys=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']`. In that case you get the output you mention in the answer:

```
+---+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| id|   a|   b|   c|   d|   e|   f|   g|
+---+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|  1|  av|  bv|null|null|  ev|  fv|null|
|  2|null|null|  cv|null|null|null|  gv|
+---+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

By the way - what you want to do is not what is called `explode` in Spark. `explode` in Spark is for the situation when you create multiple rows from one. E.g. if you wanted to get from dataframe like this:

```
+---+---------+
| id|      arr|
+---+---------+
|  1|   [a, b]|
|  2|[c, d, e]|
+---+---------+
```

to this:

```
+---+-------+
| id|element|
+---+-------+
|  1|      a|
|  1|      b|
|  2|      c|
|  2|      d|
|  2|      e|
+---+-------+
```

Comment: I liked your solution but I am restricted to use spark 2.2 which does not have sql functions you use in your code.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a solution which should work on 2.2.0 (using UDFs).

Comment: Thanks, Alexander for the quick turn around. I will run it on a bigger dataset and evaluate the performance.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using hogher order functions without exploding the arrays like:

```
d1.select('id',
          f.when(f.size(f.expr('''filter(list1,x->x._1='a')'''))>0,f.concat_ws(',',f.expr('''transform(filter(list1,x->x._1='a'),value->value._2)'''))).alias('a'),\
          f.when(f.size(f.expr('''filter(list1,x->x._1='b')'''))>0,f.concat_ws(',',f.expr('''transform(filter(list1,x->x._1='b'),value->value._2)'''))).alias('b'),\
          f.when(f.size(f.expr('''filter(list1,x->x._1='c')'''))>0,f.concat_ws(',',f.expr('''transform(filter(list1,x->x._1='c'),value->value._2)'''))).alias('c'),\
          f.when(f.size(f.expr('''filter(list1,x->x._1='d')'''))>0,f.concat_ws(',',f.expr('''transform(filter(list1,x->x._1='d'),value->value._2)'''))).alias('d'),\
          f.when(f.size(f.expr('''filter(list2,x->x._1='e')'''))>0,f.concat_ws(',',f.expr('''transform(filter(list2,x->x._1='e'),value->value._2)'''))).alias('e'),\
          f.when(f.size(f.expr('''filter(list2,x->x._1='f')'''))>0,f.concat_ws(',',f.expr('''transform(filter(list2,x->x._1='f'),value->value._2)'''))).alias('f'),\
          f.when(f.size(f.expr('''filter(list2,x->x._1='g')'''))>0,f.concat_ws(',',f.expr('''transform(filter(list2,x->x._1='g'),value->value._2)'''))).alias('g'),\
          f.when(f.size(f.expr('''filter(list2,x->x._1='h')'''))>0,f.concat_ws(',',f.expr('''transform(filter(list2,x->x._1='h'),value->value._2)'''))).alias('h')\
          ).show()


+---+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| id|   a|   b|   c|   d|   e|   f|   g|   h|
+---+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|  1|  av|  bv|null|null|  ev|  fv|null|null|
|  2|null|null|  cv|null|null|null|  gv|null|
+---+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

Hope it helps

Comment: This answer would be helpful if I did not get any error as below:     raise ParseException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
pyspark.sql.utils.ParseException: u"\nextraneous input '>' expecting {'(',

Comment: (line 1, pos 15)\n\n== SQL ==\nfilter(list1,x->x._1='a')\n---------------^^^\n" I think it can't execute value -> value._2 for some reason

Comment: it is running fine in version 2.4.4 though

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this in an alternative way:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import concat, explode, first

d1 = spark.createDataFrame([("1", [("a", "av"), ("b", "bv")], [("e", "ev"), ("f", "fv")]), \
                            ("2", [("c", "cv")], [("g", "gv")])], ["id", "list1", "list2"])

d2 = d1.withColumn('concat', concat('list1', 'list2'))
d3 = d2.withColumn('explode', explode('concat'))
d4 = d3.groupby('id').pivot('explode._1').agg(first('explode._2'))

d4.show()
+---+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|id |a   |b   |c   |e   |f   |g   |
+---+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|1  |av  |bv  |null|ev  |fv  |null|
|2  |null|null|cv  |null|null|gv  |
+---+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).